# Sound clips in chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Would it be possible to enable the user to upload audio clips, and display the players as a 'onebox' in chatrooms?

I was thinking of an audio clip 'onebox' looking like this:
[image: Audio clip]

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote?

Comment: The down votes express disagreement and in case of feature requests it signals: *No, I don't want this feature*, which is the reason I down voted. See the [meta-help] on how voting is different here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't see the advantage of it for normal SO users and it is likely going to be abused by spammers. You would have to set up an additional review queue to check that the contents of these snippets do not contain spam, obsolete or outright inappropriate content.